# I can't find htdocs in oracle server 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-fusion-middleware

My problem on this week 
My friend gave me his server which is Application Server 10g, 
the problem is EX:

```
http://xxxx.com/PPROD/  twbkwbis.P_ValLogin
```

I find  path where the 
http://xxxx.com on server which is

```
/u01/app/sct/ssb/SCT/webdocs
```

and when I add filed such `a.html` files on this path
its showing on  `http://xxxx.com/a.html`
the problem is I can't find where this path is

```
/PPROD/twbkwbis.P_ValLogin
```

all what I find on this path is this 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3wei.jpg

and even if I create dir handle with this name

```
/PPROD/
```

nothing is happening

So my question is where can I find this `/PPROD/` path

Comment: Please start by [reading the documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/core.1012/b14126/toc.htm). AS can server static pages from the webdocs directory (or whatever is configured), but it also - mostly - serves database content. PPROD is configured to serve seomthing from the database; looks like from a `twbkwbis` package, but I don't know much about it either. Maybe your friend can walk you through the basic configuration?

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Alex, My friend In vacation, So I understand from your answer that PPROD not path, so its sort of package,  right? So is this package has physical file that I can edit or add code like html php etc... Thank you so much again

Comment: sorry if i bother you, But plz help me on the next question Mr Alex

Comment: It's either a Java package, in a JAR or WAR file that you would need the source code to modify; or - more likely I think - a PL/SQL package stored in the database, which you could perhaps edit through SQL Developer. It isn't a technology I use, so I can't help much.

Comment: thank you for answer Last question  where the path for JAR or WAR    PL/SQL

Comment: Plz I promise its the last question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Mr Alex Poole 
The answer downbelow

> Please start by reading the documentaion. AS can server static pages
>   from the webdocs directory (or whatever is configured), but it also -
>   mostly - serves database content. PPROD is configured to serve
>   seomthing from the database; looks like from a twbkwbis package, but I
>   don't know much about it either. Maybe your friend can walk you
>   through the basic configuration? –  Alex Poole May 23 at 18:58